# mvc4 vs2010 iis7 - set server auhentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

so my problem Erises as i refuse to advance nor to vs2012/15 nor to mvc 6 i think is the latest and nor using EF... well latest.

as the configuration i am in :

windows 7 .net 4.03... mvc4 iis7

i have a problem adding a new website/application so i could simply publish using built-in arrangement via vs2010... instead..as i did with webforms(my till now approach) copying source to wwwroot by my self.

so the issue is i can not find any article /tutorial to set it correctly as the guidance is to set via web platform referencing this age of versions is via using older Wplatform that has `Install Web Deploy` - via using option in list "Recommended Server Configuration for Web Hosting Providers" which does not exist in current wplatform... 
[image]

update i forgot to mention i did not want to set any kind of athuresation till i know what will be the effect and what problems in connectivity to the application it will apply from other hand how easy will it be to hack even via spoofing no sweat

Answer (score 0):

as it seems the problem till now was the access permit  to the folder of the project i suggest to not use the vs studio as the folder of the project but to make a copy on a normal directory otherwise u need to set user as the user of iis asp.net iis/nameofpool and give it a read right ...full rights accessing the folder.